# Can I maintain two user collections in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nodejs-server

I am new to node and practicing it...

I have a requirement where user will have a profile section Where he fills lot of data like his educational details , employment details , address , and many other details.

As of now I am creating user collection on signup.

Can I maintain the a separate collection for profile details and whenever user details updated I will update initial registered collection also

Is this a good approach or do I need to maintain only one collection.

Can some one suggest me which is the best

Comment: If you would need to access or update the information from both collections in a single transaction, then generally you might want to lean towards having just a single user collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is **not uncommon** to have more than 1 or more user collection, for at the very least, passwords should not be in the same collection of other public data.

You could also end up with different user collection of

- personal data
- sensitive data
- browsing history

etc. All referenced by the same user _id

Data however, should in the best scenario, not be overlapped. Hence so there should only a single source of truth of value, except for _id which is used for referencing.

If you update a value in one collection, you should not need to update same value in another colletion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a single user collection with other info like educational details in it.

In mongo, there is no use in having a different collection and maintain the relationship between them. Your queries will be a little bit expensive if you store the data in a different collection.